# How to update time in lua to reflect system timezone change during execution?

Tags: lua, timezone, awesome-wm

### Problem

I want to modify the `awful.widget.textclock` widget in awesome-wm to immediately reflect a change in the system timezone.  This widget and all of the awesome-wm config is written in lua.

Currently, if the system timezone is changed the widget continues to display the time according to the timezone set at runtime.  The widget uses the `os.time` function to retrieve the time, but this does not match the system time.

---

### Solution as provided below

lua script:

```
local tz=require"luatz";

require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()
print("Before Changes (America/Los_Angeles)")
print(os.date("!%H:%M",tz.time_in()))

os.execute("timedatectl set-timezone America/Chicago")

require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()
print("America/Chicago")
print(os.date("!%H:%M",tz.time_in()))

os.execute("timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York")
require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()

print("America/New_York")
print(os.date("!%H:%M",tz.time_in()))
```

Output:

```
Before Changes (America/Los_Angeles)
15:33
America/Chicago
17:33
America/New_York
18:33
```

---

### Workaround

This can be resolved by restarting awesome window manager, which causes the widget to get the correct timezone again.  Naturally, if the timezone changes this requires another restart of the window manager.

The desired effect is to update the timezone from the system when it changes, either periodically or every time the `os.time` function is called.

---

### Use Case

If you are curious, the use case for this is on a laptop.  I travel frequently and run `tzupdate` on a `systemd timer`.  I would like to automate changing my timezone.  This works fine except that the widget which actually displays the time doesn't notice the system timezone change.

---

### Tried so far

1. Unset the '$TZ' environment variable.  But Arch Linux never sets this variable in the first place, so I am unsure how lua even determines the correct timezone.
2. Use the `luatz` library and specifically the `tzcache.clear_tz_cache()` function.  This seems to have no effect.
3. Retrieve the system time with functions other than `os.time()`: `luatz.time()` and `luatz.gettime.gettime()`.  These retrieve the same time as the other functions.
4. Use the `luatz.time_in()` function, but this returns the time with the timezone offset applied twice to UTC time.  `luatz.time()` returns the correct local time, but is supposed to return UTC time.

---

### UPDATED `luatz`

I tried messing with the `luatz` library as recommended, but it doesn't seem to recheck the system timezone, even after calling the `tzcache.clear_tz_cache()` function.

I cloned the `luatz` repo and copied `luatz` to the system modules directory.  The script seems to load correctly, but has not changed the effect of ignoring the system timezone change.  As far as I can tell, this does not do anything differently than the `os.time()` function.

luatz test script:

```
local luatz = require "luatz"
local tzcache = require "luatz.tzcache"
local gettime = require "luatz.gettime"

print ("\nBefore Change - System TZ is ")
os.execute("timedatectl | grep 'Time zone' | awk '{ print $3 }'")
print("\nos.time(): "..os.date("%H:%M", os.time()))
print("luatz.time(): "..os.date("%H:%M", luatz.time()))
print("gettime..gettime(): "..os.date("%H:%M", gettime.gettime()))

print("\nTime zone changed to America/New_York")
os.execute("timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York")

tzcache.clear_tz_cache()

print ("\nAfter  Change - System TZ is ")
os.execute("timedatectl | grep 'Time zone' | awk '{ print $3 }'")
print ("\nos.time(): "..os.date("%H:%M", os.time()))
print ("luatz.time(): "..os.date("%H:%M", luatz.time()))
print("gettime.gettime(): "..os.date("%H:%M", gettime.gettime()))
```

Output:

```
Before Change - System TZ is 
America/Los_Angeles

os.time(): 11:54
luatz.time(): 11:54
gettime..gettime(): 11:54

Time zone changed to America/New_York

After  Change - System TZ is 
America/New_York

os.time(): 11:54
luatz.time(): 11:54
gettime.gettime(): 11:54
```

---

### `luatz.time_in()`

So the `luatz.time_in()` function does update as the system time zone changes and I am excited about that!  However, `time_in()` does not display the correct local time.  It adds the timezone offset to the correct local time, resulting in the time being several hours behind.  I experimented with setting the `TZ` environment variable, but this had no effect.  For some reason, `luatz.time()` is returning local time and `luatz.time_in()` is returning the result of applying the timezone offset twice.

lua script:

```
local tz=require"luatz";

require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()
print("Before Changes (America/Los_Angeles)")
print(os.date("%H:%M",tz.time_in()))

os.execute("timedatectl set-timezone America/Chicago")

require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()
print("America/Chicago")
print(os.date("%H:%M",tz.time_in()))

os.execute("timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York")
require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()

print("America/New_York")
print(os.date("%H:%M",tz.time_in()))
```

output:

```
Before Changes (America/Los_Angeles)
08:59
America/Chicago
10:59
America/New_York
11:59
```

Actual system local time: `15:59`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low level function behind [`os.date`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#os_date), [`localtime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) "acts as if it called [`tzset(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset)", `tzset` uses the environmental variable `TZ` to determine the timezone, and if that doesn't exist, read from `/etc/localtime`.

Environmental variables are mostly determined before your program starts, therefore, to get your timezone change to take place, you could find a way to set your `TZ` variable. A `os.setenv` is available via a few lua libraries, e.g. [lua-ex](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal)

If that doesn't seem a reasonable course of action, you might be able to just ensure your script is started without `TZ` set at all; which will force `tzset` to read from `/etc/localtime`. Sadly, most of the time this file is cached, and you will not get updates; this depends on your system.

Alternatively, you could use a different library to obtain the time, instead of the `os` library. In [`luatz`](https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz) you can clear it's timezone cache with `require "luatz.tzcache".clear_tz_cache()`, you could call this function before fetching the time.

Comment: I am running arch linux which does not set the TZ environment variable already.  `echo $TZ` returns nothing at the command line so I am not sure that is an option.  I will look into `luatz`.

Comment: the `luatz` functions also continue to return the incorrect system time even after clearing the `tzcache`.

Comment: `luatz.time()` is UTC time. `luatz.time_in()` is local time. try this code: http://codepad.org/3nt9p4Ub

Comment: I tried `luatz.time_in()` and although it changes as the system timezone changes, it doesn't report the correct local time.  Any ideas?

Comment: `os.date` adds the current system timezone offset. `time_in` has already adjusted it for you. prefix your date format string with `!` to prevent that. `print(os.date("!%H:%M",tz.time_in()))`

Comment: Thanks!  This is the solution.  I added my test script to the question for clarity.

Comment: Btw, instead of polling to see if the timezone changed, you can subscribe to notifications via DBus: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated/