# Lua Retrieving time in UTC returns local time anyway

Tags: time, lua, utc, iguana-ui

I am using Lua in Iguana (Interfaceware)

I have server that's located in AEST timezone and I am trying to get time in UTC like this:

```
   trace(os.time(os.date('!*t'))) 
   trace(os.time(os.date('*t')))
   trace(os.time(os.date('!%c')))
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]
It keeps returning local time instead of UTC.

Am I missing something?

The server is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Are tables returned by `os.date("!*t")` and `os.date("*t")` contain he same time?  What is the output of  `print(os.date("!*t").hour, os.date("*t").hour)` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes both tables are identical.
And also both contain identical .hour

Comment: Your OS doesn't have correct information about your timezone (wrong settings, absence of synchronization with a time server, etc.). Make the correction manually: `os.time()-11*60*60`

Answer (score 0):

To get time in UTC use `!` :

```
os.date('!%c')
```

check your time zone first by this code

```
local now = os.time()
localtime_minus_UTC = os.difftime(os.time(os.date("*t", now)),
                                  os.time(os.date("!*t", now)))
```

Comment: that is mean your timezone is utc

Comment: If it's UTC - Shouldn't it be returning os.time() as 09:49 (Right now) ? 

Instead it returns 20:49

Comment: now os.time local and UTC are the same in your machine

Comment: In that case: "os.date("!*t")" should return 09:52 (right now) ? 
Yet everything returns 20:52 (+11 Hours)

Comment: If time set os.date('!%c') should return  09:55 !

Comment: Server time is set as 20:57 (AEST time) 

Surely server can't be in UTC yet have time set as 20:57?

Comment: look at this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212106/how-to-update-time-in-lua-to-reflect-system-timezone-change-during-execution